# Android CardView OnClick to start a new activity not working

Tags: android, android-activity

I am currently working on an emergency app that dials service short codes or numbers when a user clicks on a card.

So far, i have been able to achieve the dialing feature but i want to start a new activity from one of the cards instead of dialing a number.

I tried using an intent to start the new activity from the OnClick Method but my app crashes while other cards works perfectly well

Below is the error message generated by the IDE and the CardviewDataAdapter.java code.
[image: The error message screen shot]
CardViewDataAdapter.java Code:

```
public class CardViewDataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CardViewDataAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<ItemObject> itemList;


    public CardViewDataAdapter(Context context, List<ItemObject> itemList) {
        this.itemList = itemList;
    }

    // Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public CardViewDataAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                             int viewType) {
        // create a new view
        View itemLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
                R.layout.cardview_row, null);


        //Todo: set the view's size, margins, paddings and layout parameters
        // create ViewHolder
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(itemLayoutView);
        return viewHolder;


    }

    // Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {

        // - get data from your itemsData at this position
        // - replace the contents of the view with that itemsData
        viewHolder.image_view.setImageResource(itemList.get(position).getPhoto());
        viewHolder.image_name.setText(itemList.get(position).getName());

    }


    // Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return this.itemList.size();
    }

    // Provide a reference to the views for each data item
    // Complex data items may need more than one view per item, and
    // you provide access to all the views for a data item in a view holder
    // inner class to hold a reference to each item of RecyclerView
    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        // each data item is a string and an image in this case
        public ImageView image_view;
        public TextView image_name;
        public Context context;


        public ViewHolder(View itemLayoutView) {


            super(itemLayoutView);
            this.image_view = (ImageView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.image_view);
            this.image_name = (TextView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.image_name);

            // Attach a click listener to the entire row view
            itemLayoutView.setOnClickListener(this);
            itemLayoutView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "OnLongClick Version :" + getAdapterPosition(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;
                }
            });




        }


        // Handles the row being being clicked
        @Override

        public void onClick(View view) {


            if (getAdapterPosition() == 0) {
                Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:123"));
                view.getContext().startActivity(callIntent);
            } else if (getAdapterPosition() == 1) {
                Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:1234"));
                view.getContext().startActivity(callIntent);
            } else if (getAdapterPosition() == 2) {
                //intent =  new Intent(mContext, TutorialActivity.class);
                Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:12345"));
                view.getContext().startActivity(callIntent);
            } else if (getAdapterPosition() == 3) {
                Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:123456"));
                view.getContext().startActivity(callIntent);
            }else if (getAdapterPosition() == 4){
                view.getContext().startActivity(new Intent(view.getContext(),safetyActivity.class));
            }
            else {
                view.getContext().startActivity(new Intent(view.getContext(),safetyActivity.class));
            }

        }


    }


}
```

Comment: You miss the declaration of Activity in manifest.

Comment: Rather copy the contents of logcat than take a picture of it ( in your picture the first line is cut off ). And when you do copy them, use **code** format for them since it's easier to read.

Comment: @Vucko thanks but I copied all the error messages, the ones below are irrelevant.

Comment: Yes, but the first line is very relevant and you cut it off. Did you try @ssh's comment, are you missing your activity in the manifest?

Comment: @ssh I couldn't believe my brain is so forgetful to add the activity to the manifest. Thanks it worked like magic!

Comment: I suppose question should be closed due to elementary miss.

Comment: @ssh, Please kindly post the answer  so i can mark it solved

Comment: @KennyDexter will be better if you delete the question. Is the one of the most often mistake.

Comment: i get you, its surely basic error! i am getting it deleted right away. @ssh

Answer (score -1):

You're getting this exception because you're trying to start activity that isn't declared in your Manifest.